# vector addition assignment with `std::transform`

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Which kind of Output Iterator do I need to use in `std::transform` to implement vector addition assignment:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator+=(std::vector<T>& lhs, std::vector<T> const& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.size() == rhs.size())
    {
        std::transform(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), /*Output Iterator*/, std::plus<T>());
        return lhs;
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument("operands must be of same size");
}
```

`std::transform` is implemented in the following way:

```
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, 
         class OutputIt, class BinaryOperation>
OutputIt transform(InputIt first1, InputIt last1, InputIt first2, 
                   OutputIt d_first, BinaryOperation binary_op)
{
    while (first1 != last1) {
        *d_first++ = binary_op(*first1++, *first2++);
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

So, `OutputIt` needs to start at `lhs.begin()` and replace all the values up to `lhs.end()`. I'm sure there is some kind of standard functionality already implemented.

Comment: Were you trying to bring `std::back_inserter` to mind?

Comment: Please don't do `std::vector<T>`; do `C<T, A>`, with all three parameters deduced. Or if you really only want this to work with vectors, at least add `A` in.

Comment: BTW this operator shouldn't exist. Intuitively it means "concatenate the elements" but you've got it as "sum the elements index-wise", which is just one obvious example of why adding non-standard operators for things is a bad idea.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Intuitively, as a mathematician, the `+` operator between two vectors means vector addition.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: And intuitively, as a programmer, the `+` operator between two arrays or array-like containers means element-wise concatenation. You see the problem here?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, the problem is that intuition is subjective, but don't mind - I see your point.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: If you wish.

Comment: You could use `std::valarray` if you want to use `+=` in this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just pass `lhs.begin()` again: you want to overwrite the existing values of `lhs` with the new ones.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Don't know why I didn't see this obvious solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If I have two `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` objects `a` and `b`, `a + b` won't compile (since `std::plus<T>()` can't see the new operator for `std::vector<T>`). Placing the operators in the `std`-namespace is a solution - but a bad one. Overloading the `std::plus<T> struct` would be a better one. Any other ideas?

Comment: You're not supposed to overload operators for types that don't contain user-defined types, and `vector<vector<T>>` doesn't - the placeholder T doesn't count. So there really is no good solution. Your compiler will probably accept it if you put the overload in `std`, but it's undefined behavior.